# Angular get different values from nodejs API

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, api

If I try to call a get on my nodeJS than it's work but I get different values.
I have to submit my search parameters 1-3 times to get the right output.
My Node server get the right search parameter and output the right API response but if I want to print it to my Angular app then it will use a old parameters. I don't understand the behavior.

Request Path:
angular -> nodeJS -> 3rd partie API -> nodeJS -> angular

Is that path wrong? how can I get the current data for angular?

APP.JS

```
    app.get('/url', (req, res) => {
    var name = req.query.searchname;
    console.log("Output\n---------------------------")
    console.log(req.query.searchname);
    doGetRequest(name);
    
    return res.send(data);
})
```

test.service

```
test(searchName){

    this.http.get<any>('http://localhost:3000/url', {
      params: {
        searchname: searchName
      }}).subscribe(data => this.totalAngularPackages = data)
    this.log();
    
  }

log(){
  console.log(this.totalAngularPackages);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `this.totalAngularPackages` is assigned asynchronously. Any statements that directly depend on it must be inside the subscription. By the time the `console.log` is run, the variable `this.totalAngularPackages` is still undefined or holds the previously assigned values. You could learn more about async requests [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/6513921).

```js
test(searchName) {
  this.http.get<any>('http://localhost:3000/url', {params: {searchname: searchName}})
    .subscribe(data => {
      this.totalAngularPackages = data;
      this.log(); // <-- must be inside the subscription
    });
}

log() {
  console.log(this.totalAngularPackages);
}
```

Comment: I try it but it doesnt work for me. I try to output data instead of totalAngularPackages and have the same issue.

Comment: I test my nodeJS server. It transmit the old data. I checked the data after the function doGetRequest and they are deprecated. Is it possible to wait until I retrieve the right data?